# Python: Using split on a string and returning a tuple?

Tags: python

Say I do the following:

```
>>> a = foo@bar.com
>>> uname, domain = a.split('@')
```

But what if I only ever want domain, and never uname? For example, if I only ever wanted uname and not domain, I could do this:

```
>>> uname, = a.split('@')
```

Is there a better way to split a into a tuple and have it throw away uname?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To take into account some of the other answers, you have the following options:

If you know that the string will have an '@' symbol in it then you can simply do the following:

```
>>> domain = a.split('@')[1]
```

If there is a chance that you don't have an '@' symbol, then one of the following is suggested:

```
>>> domain = a.partition('@')[2]
```

Or

```
try:
    domain = a.split('@')[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Oops! No @ symbols exist!"
```

Comment: There's a reason why split and partition both exist. Sometimes split is the right thing to use, but this is not one of those times.

Comment: Can you please explain when to use split and when to use partition?

Answer (score 6):

You *could* use your own coding style and specify something like "use '_' as *don't care* for variables whose value you want to ignore". This is a general practice in other languages like Erlang.

Then, you could just do:

```
uname, _ = a.split('@')
```

And according to the rules you set out, the value in the _ variable is to be ignored. As long as you consistently apply the rule, you should be OK.

Comment: This use of `_` is actually quite well established, see [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/699305).

Answer (score 4):

If you **know** there's always an `@` in your string, `domain = a.split('@')[1]` is the way to go. Otherwise check for it first or add a `try..except IndexError` block aroudn it.

Comment: You might also consider `domain = a.partition('@')[2]`. This will set `domain` to `''` if there is no `@` in the string, and will also only split on the first `@` if there is more than one.

Answer (score 4):

This gives you an empty string if there's no @:

```
    >>> domain = a.partition('@')[2]
```

If you want to get the original string back when there's no @, use this:

```
    >>> domain = a.rpartition('@')[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
domain = a[a.index("@") + 1:]
```